# #undef not work as expected in my C program

Tags: c, header-files

I am writing linear list ADT as my practice in DS class. I use one header file, one function source code and a driver as a whole project. I defined macro "ELEMENT_TYPE" and "MAXSIZE" in the header file. My design is that I can #undef  and immediately #define those two macros in the driver program to change "ELEMENT_TYPE" to any type the driver need.
If I put these code:

```
#undef ELEMENT_TYPE
#define ELEMENT_TYPE char
#undef MAXSIZE
#define MAXSIZE 50
```

into the header file after the #define, then in the driver program, the functions can be recognized properly(For example, insertion() 's second augment was "ELEMENT_TYPE", use those code above, IDE shows that insertion() receive a char augment in driver program.) However, if I put those codes into the driver below #include "foo.h", then IDE cannot recognize what augments the fuction should receive and use the initial definition of "ELEMENT_TYPE", in this case, int. Who know what was wrong in my program so that preprocessing directives don't work properly?

Here are the original codes:
driver.c
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6B76vmk6nN/

linear_list.c
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SHq4W5zkGM/

linear_list.h
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VY8vcgFD89/

PS:I am not native English speaker, so maybe there are some places I didn't express clearly. Point them out and I'll add more details if needed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  If your program is C, don't use the C++ tag.  If it is C++, don't use the C tag.  Using both annoys people — and annoyed people are apt to down-vote.  You need to show your code in the question; paste-bin links are not acceptable (except perhaps as backup).  Read about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]) too.

Comment: What does your compiler do?  Does it get confused, or is it just your IDE?  Which IDE are you using?  On which platform?  Now you know one more reason that people are not necessarily fans of IDEs.  You also know a reason why Stroustrup would like to get rid of the preprocessor from C++.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://wandbox.org/permlink/8LU7zVOiPLyyTTwY , but please, note the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it sounds like is happening is you're trying to `#define` these values in the driver in the hopes that they will stay defined in linear_list.c.

The problem is that these files are compiled separately and then linked. The `#define`s placed in driver.c cannot change those found in linear_list.c.

In order to have the effect I think you would like, you will need to change these values in linear_list.h. This is the best way to do this because that header is included in both the source files, and will presumably be `#include`d in any file that works with the functions defined in linear_list.c. Please bear in mind that in order to see a change in the behavior of your program you will need to recompile not only driver.c but linear_list.c after changes to linear_list.h have been made.

As a side note, you should generally `#include` local headers like linear_list.h after you `#include` global headers like stdio.h and stdlib.h. In linear_list.c either of those headers could overwrite the values you've used in linear_list.h, if those identifiers are used. They look like they could be common enough, that it's not implausible that some header may use them, so it may be worthwhile to use a more unique identifier in the future. Which leads me to my final point: using `#undef` on these identifiers without checking if they're used somewhere else could lead to some problems, so you should generally check with `#ifndef`.

Hope that helps. If I've misunderstood please correct me.

**EDIT:** Clarification, additional information, credit to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49253815/5717938) for reminding me of some important practices.

Answer (score 0):

Macros in source code are replaced with the macro definition in effect at that point where the macro is used in the source code. So function declarations using `ELEMENT_TYPE` use the macro definition that most recently precedes the declaration. Changing the macro later will not change the function definition.

An alternative is to define `ELEMENT_TYPE` in the header only if it is not already defined:

```
#if ! defined ELEMENT_TYPE
    #define ELEMENT_TYPE char
#endif
```

Then a source file can do either of:

- Do not define `ELEMENT_TYPE` itself. When the header is included, the default type of `char` will be used.
- Define `ELEMENT_TYPE`, then include the header. If desired, `#undef ELEMENT_TYPE` afterward. The type the source file provides in `ELEMENT_TYPE` will be used.

The driver and the program that uses it must use the same type. You cannot compile the driver using one type and the program using another. Compiling the program with a different type will not change the driver.